# Windows 10 - Cannot connect to SMB shares

Tags: windows, network-shares, samba, smb

Within my home network, the network drives [SMB shares] set up on a Surface 4 Pro [Windows 10 Home v2004, b19041.985], connected via ethernet, suddenly stopped working, and since the same are readily available on another Windows 10 machine, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the servers [Ubuntu server and QNAP NAS].

- The server is visible from the Surface 4 Pro, as pinging the server works, both using its hostname [`servername`] and IP address [`192.168.1.3`], with roundtrip times of <1ms and no lost packets, however:

  - `net use X: \\servername\sharename` returns `error 59`
  - `net use X: \\192.168.1.3\sharename` returns `error 67`
- I have, to no avail:

  - enabled File and Printer Sharing, Network Discovery and File Sharing
  - restarted several times
  - tried disabling Windows Defender firewall *(nothing changed)*

Any suggestions?

Comment: One common reason for Error 67 when using IP addressing is a DNS issue. Try running TCP/IP reset on each machine, restart each and try again:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: A bit of a clutch at straws, but might be worth checking for conflicting I.P. address? If you've assigned a static to your server, but not successfully excluded that from your dynamic range something else might be trying to use the same I.P. ? (I'd start with the surface TBH, seeing as everything else is working).

Comment: @John: Was certainly worth trying, but that did not help.

Comment: @GregHNZ: I checked, but nothing else has been assigned that IP address. And, again, I am able to ping that machine, and I also can SCP into the server and everything, so I think the Surface actually has no issue getting through to the server. Besides, as I said, there are actually two different servers (the second being a QNAP NAS), and those two cannot have the same IP, obviously, but still connecting to the shares on both does not work, so I think it's not an IP conflict. Thanks, however, for the suggestion. Any more ideas?

Comment: @John: Sorry, wanted to add more: I think the idea of there beign some sort of hiccup that manifested itself in wrong cached data sounds indeed promising. Any more such ideas? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @hihp Just an FYI, never disable Windows Defender Firewall, unless using a 3rd party firewall, as there are no system-related functions without default firewall rules allowing their traffic. If believing the default rules are a potential issue, referencing the applicable application's/service's [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com) page would be recommended to compare what firewall rules to search for _(google: `Microsoft Docs <app/service name>`)_, but flat out disabling the firewall of any network connected PC is unwise at best and would never be recommended as a troubleshooting step.

Comment: @hihp Regarding accessing shares via DNS hostname: in order to do so without issue in Windows, three things must be correctly configured: **(1)** Local domain of router, server, & PC must match - the Workgroup name is the local domain name in Windows: `SysDm.cpl` → _Computer Name_ → _Change..._ → _Member of: Workgroup_ → `LocalDomain`→ OK → Reboot; **(2)** `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file must list the server in the format of: `<IP>  <Hostname>  <HostName.LocalDomain>` _([example](https://pastebin.com/9bx2tRst))_; **(3)** Traffic allowed on TCP: `139`, `445`
UDP `137`, `138`, `139`

Comment: @JW0914: Thanks for clearing up my question. I will attempt to be more concise in the future. As regards your other comments: As I said, the shares where working before, I had not touched any workgroup settings etc. (and of course I checked them), O I knew that could not be the case. And as for disabling the firewall: I think it os totally legit to deactivate it for testing purposes, even if it is just to rule it out. Shopuld it turn out to be a firewall issue, the next stept obviously would not be to keep it disabled, but to find out what changed to suddenly the firewall blocks it...

Comment: @hihp Shares will always work, but if wanting to traverse shares by hostname, and not IP, you'll eventually run into issues if those three things aren't  done _(without the PC's local domain [Workgroup] name matching the router's/DNS Server's and share server's, a static IP set for the share server on the router/DNS server, and an entry in the Windows `hosts` file, Windows lacks a route to the share server by hostname)_

Comment: @JW0914: As I stated in the actual question, accessing the share did not work even when using the IP address, since the Work Station Service wasn't running. Besides, (a) I also have an nmbd daemon running for resolving NetBIOS requests, and (b) have set up a WSD server daemon to help Windows see the services on my Linux server. I am not too proficient in these things, but one of those methods appears to be helping Windows resolve the servername, because I never edited the hosts file by hand ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by trying a simple `net use` without any parameters to see what I would get and received `error 1222`, leading me to investigate whether the work station service [`lanmansworkstation`] was running and it was not; I started it, but it returned `a dependency could not be found`.

In Registry Editor:

1. ```
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation
   ```

   I changed the value of `REG_MULTI_SZ`: `DependOnService` from `mrxsmb10` to: 
    <sup>*(as far as I can see, `mrxsmb10` is related to SMB 1.0, which I am not using)*</sup>

   ```
   bowser
   mrxsmb20
   nsi
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** `bowser` must be spelled this way</sup>
2. ```
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\mrxsmb20
   ```

   I changed the value of `DWORD`: `Start` to `2` [Start Automatically]
3. ```
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\mrxsmb
   ```

   Service `mrxsmb20` is dependent on service `mrxsmb`, so I also changed the value of `DWORD`: `Start` to `2`
4. I rebooted and the workstation service was still not running, so I went into `services.msc` and started it manually; et voilá, network shares work again